# Centering the logo even with different monitor/resolution

Tags: html, css

I want to center the logo. I was able to center it by defining the padding and stuff but the problem is that the logo moves when I try to view it on a different monitor/resolution.

Here's the Code:

```css
/* Navigation */
.navbar {-moz-border-radius: 0;-webkit-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;margin-bottom: 0;}
.navbar .container {text-align: center; position: center; background-color: #fff; right:55px;}
.navbar-default {-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-out;width: 100%;border: none;border-bottom: 0px solid #e7e7e7;background-color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {color: #000;font-weight: normal;font-size: 15px; display: inline-block; padding-right: 23px; padding-left: 23px}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {background-color: transparent;color: #005FA6;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {background-color: transparent;color: #005FA6;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:focus {color: #005FA6;background-color: transparent;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {margin: 10px 0 0 15px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {border: none;background: #f3f3f3;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle i {font-size: 31px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {float: right; border-top: none;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;}
.navbar-brand>img {padding: 5px; align: center;}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="img/corelogo.png" alt="" height="150" width="150">
    </a>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Set your logo `<img>` tag as `display:block`. Then give it a left and right margin of `auto`.

Example below:

```css
/* Navigation */

.navbar {
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar .container {
  text-align: center;
  position: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  right: 55px;
}

.navbar-default {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 23px;
  padding-left: 23px
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #005FA6;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #005FA6;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active>a:focus {
  color: #005FA6;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle i {
  font-size: 31px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  float: right;
  border-top: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:block;
  margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="img/corelogo.png" alt="" height="150" width="150">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I made a small edit. You actually set the styles on `<img>` and not on `<a>`.

Comment: It didn't move from the left :( I might be doing it wrong idk

Comment: There might be context around the snippet you posted affecting this. Try setting the `<a>` container as display block as well. You can also place the whole thing inside a `<div>`. A block level element will take the whole width of its parent container unless a width is specified and will break into a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You just need make your image a block element by adding `display: block;` and then adding an auto margin with `margin: 0 auto;`

Here is your code: `.navbar-brand > img { display: block; margin: 0 auto;}`

```
<style>
.navbar {-moz-border-radius: 0;-webkit-border-radius: 0;border-radius: 0;margin-bottom: 0;}
.navbar .container {text-align: center; position: center; background-color: #fff; right:55px;}
.navbar-default {-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;transition: all 0.3s ease-out;width: 100%;border: none;border-bottom: 0px solid #e7e7e7;background-color: #fff; }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {color: #000;font-weight: normal;font-size: 15px; display: inline-block; padding-right: 23px; padding-left: 23px}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {background-color: transparent;color: #005FA6;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {background-color: transparent;color: #005FA6;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:focus {color: #005FA6;background-color: transparent;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {margin: 10px 0 0;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {border: none;background: #f3f3f3;}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle i {font-size: 31px;}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {float: right; border-top: none;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;}
.navbar-brand > img { display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
      <img class="my-image" src="img/corelogo.png" alt="" height="150" width="150">
    </a>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried and tested it, it works fine.  You must have conflicting code elsewhere

Comment: That's actually my problem, I tried everything and I can't find that conflicting code...